# Nuxt 3: How to verify if a component was rendered on the client?

Tags: netlify, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, netlify-form

I'm using netlify forms in my nuxt 3 app, but found out it only logs submissions if the component was rendered with `ssr: false` (`nuxt.config.ts`).

However I **do** want to deploy my website with ssr enabled. So I tried wrapping the component with `<ClientOnly>` but that did not fix it. Although I'm absolutely sure the problem lies with the server side rendering, purely for that piece of code.

So is there a way to verify when something is being rendered on the client vs on the server?